# "You cannot transfer or cancel as you are not currently registered for this event."

Tags: civievent

CiviCRM  5.16.3
Logged on as Administrator
Can not click 'Transfer or Cancel' on event tab or detail of event registration without receiving error: "You cannot transfer or cancel as you are not currently registered for this event"

Ideas?

edit - we installed this (https://github.com/lcdservices/biz.lcdservices.moveparticipant) in a pinch and it worked.

Also noticed that this is a pending/pay-later event registration, could that be why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also noticed that this is a pending/pay-later event registration, could that be why?

Yes, according to the latest code till 5.19.1, I see transfer or cancel is only possible for participant with status = `Registered`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We let people register and then pay later, but sometimes they call in and want those choices to go to their spouse or another member of their organization, who will show up and pay. Our registration choices are long so re-entering sucks. The extension I linked permits the move, any reason core does not?

Comment: It might be a bug and could be raised at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/new for some discussion. I just think this part of the code is not altered frequently due to which is it not observed yet.

Comment: Proposition to change the behaviour here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23164 (CiviCRM 5.50 or 5.51, if accepted).